# If JSON contains $myid then (Perl)

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to loop through JSON:

```
my $cards = $json_obj->decode( $jsoncards->content );
foreach my $card ( @$cards )
            {
                    print Dumper $card->{idMembers};
                    if ( $card->{idMembers} =~ $myid )
                    {
                            print $card->{name} . "\n";
                    }
            }
```

The output from print Dumper $card->{idMembers}; is:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '50e442a195105cde670743e4',
      '50fd66804825017002070285',
      '50f71f02a30d2a8c0d07d10d'
    ];
```

How do I compare to those ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bind operator `=~` treats its LHS as a string and the RHS as a pattern. The stringification of an arrayref looks like `ARRAY(0x12ABF14)`, so this isn't useful.

We have two possibilities to match the `$myid` against each member of the array:

1. The `grep EXPR, LIST` builtin. Selects all elements where the expression returns a true value. If the count of the returned items is ≥ 1, then a matching element was found.

   ```
   if ( grep $myid eq $_, @{ $card->{idMembers} }) { do stuff }
   # or: grep /\Q$myid/, ... if you don't want string equality
   ```
2. Use the smartmatch operator `~~` in the *member-of* meaning:

   ```
   if ( $myid ~~ $card->{idMembers} ) { do stuff }
   ```

   This is subjects to multiple caveats: (1) It is only usable since v10.1. Therefore, code using smartmatch should at least `use 5.010001`. (2) Smartmatch was re-labeled as experimental in the latest release of perl, and may change without much notice. (3) If the `idMembers` entry is *not* an array, smartmatch may hide the error.

   Smartmatch depends on the type of both operands. If you want to select all entries that contain `$myid` as a substring, you should probably pass it as a regex object: `qr/\Q$myid/ ~~ ...`. Otherwise, it will likely test for equality